Unable to add a big paragraph with multiple types of font weights in it using HeterogeneousParagraph in BORB
page = Page(width=Decimal(256), height=Decimal(256))
layout.add(
            HeterogeneousParagraph(
                [
                    ChunkOfText("Lorem "),
                    ChunkOfText("ipsum ", font_color=HexColor("56cbf9")),
                    ChunkOfText("dolor ", font_size=Decimal(8)),
                    ChunkOfText("sit ", font="Helvetica-Bold"),
                    ChunkOfText(
                        "sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk us Ifsk. "
                        "us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk.  us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk.",
                        font="Helvetica-Oblique"),
                ], text_alignment=Alignment.LEFT,respect_newlines_in_text=True,
            )
        )

I'm getting this AssertionError: HeterogeneousParagraph is too wide to fit inside column / page. Needed 1787 pts, only 476 pts available.
I'm trying to achieve something like this below:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usfLorem ipsum dolor sit sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usfLorem ipsum dolor sit sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usfLorem ipsum dolor sit sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usfLorem ipsum dolor sit sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf
But Facing this error:
File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\PDFPOC\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\PDFPOC\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\PDFPOC\WebService.py", line 27, in hello
    obj.main(person)
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\PDFPOC\NGG0027.py", line 379, in main
    layout.add(
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\PDFPOC\venv\Lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\canvas\layout\page_layout\multi_column_layout.py", line 221, in add
    assert False, f"{layout_element.__class__.__name__} is too wide to fit inside column / page. Needed {round(layout_box.get_width())} pts, only {round(available_box.get_width())} pts available."
           ^^^^^
AssertionError: HeterogeneousParagraph is too wide to fit inside column / page. Needed 1787 pts, 
only 476 pts available.


The width of your page is is too small.
If you expand them to something large enough, you will end up with an output in the PDF looking something like this.
I achieved this by using the enum the library provides like so and uses A0_PORTRAIT's width and height:
from decimal import Decimal
from borb.pdf import HexColor
from borb.pdf import Alignment
from borb.pdf import HeterogeneousParagraph
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import ChunkOfText
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf.page.page_size import PageSize
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF

doc: Document = Document()
page = Page(PageSize.A0_PORTRAIT.value[0], PageSize.A0_PORTRAIT.value[1])
doc.add_page(page)
layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page)
layout.add(
            HeterogeneousParagraph(
                [
                    ChunkOfText("Lorem "),
                    ChunkOfText("ipsum ", font_color=HexColor("56cbf9")),
                    ChunkOfText("dolor ", font_size=Decimal(8)),
                    ChunkOfText("sit ", font="Helvetica-Bold"),
                    ChunkOfText(
                        "sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk us Ifsk. "
                        "us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk.  us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk.",
                        font="Helvetica-Oblique"),
                ], text_alignment=Alignment.LEFT,respect_newlines_in_text=True,
            )
        )

with open("C:/dev/output.pdf", "wb") as out_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(out_file_handle, doc)


How to make the text wrap to the next line when the width is not enough! instead of increasing the width more than an A4! Thanks.

disclaimer: I am the author of borb
HeterogeneousParagraph only splits its content based on the LayoutElement objects you provide it.
In your case, it will not split the sk ChunkOfText because you provided that as 1 LayoutElement.
If you want HeterogeneousParagraph to be able to split its content (and thus wrap), you can split the str (on whitespace character), and add a separate ChunkOfText for each of them.
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import HeterogeneousParagraph 
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf import ChunkOfText
from borb.pdf import HexColor
from borb.pdf import PDF
import typing

doc: Document = Document()

page: Page = Page()
doc.add_page(page)

layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

# build list of chunks
l: typing.List[ChunkOfText] = []
l += [ChunkOfText("Lorem ")]
l += [ChunkOfText("ipsum ", font_color=HexColor("56cbf9"))]
l += [ChunkOfText("dolor ", font_color=HexColor('112831'))]
l += [ChunkOfText("sit ", font="Helvetica-Bold")]
l += [ChunkOfText(x+" ", font="Helvetica-oblique") for x in
                        "sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk us Ifsk. "
                        "us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk.  us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk usf sk us Ifsk us Ifsk.".split(" ")]

# add chunks
layout.add(HeterogeneousParagraph(l))

# write
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as fh:
  PDF.dumps(fh, doc)

Which outputs the following PDF:

